# Using libxml-xsd in an electron app fails with bindings error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, electron

I would like to validate an XML file based upon its schema in an electron application.

I have an angular2 service which works before the inclusion of my libxml-xsd require statement. As soon as I add this to the top of my service file:

```
const xsd = require('libxml-xsd');
```

I run `npm run build` which executes this :

```
webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached
```

I see the following new warnings in the output:

```
WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
Critical dependencies:
76:22-40 the request of a dependency is an expression
76:43-53 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/bindings/bindings.js 76:22-40 76:43-53

WARNING in ./~/bindings/README.md
Module parse failed: /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/bindings/README.md Unexpected token (2:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:3)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOp (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1656:43)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOp (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1658:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1639:17)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)
 @ ./~/bindings ^\.\/.*$
```

I then run my application by executing : `electron main.js` which then throws this error in the browsers console:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/build/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/build/Debug/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/build/Release/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/out/Debug/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/Debug/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/out/Release/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/Release/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/build/default/xmljs.node
 → /Users/myusername/Documents/Personal/MyApp/compiled/6.5.0/darwin/x64/xmljs.node
```

Could somebody please help me get libxml-xsd running under my application configuration? Does this have anything to do with webpack? If so - how do I change its config to bring in the appropriate files?

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve issue with `bindings.js` using this code from [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/issues/1101#issuecomment-213581938).

**webpack**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^mock-firmata$/),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/bindings$/, /^$/)
  ],
  externals: ["bindings"]
}
```

The problem is that `libxml-xsd` package is for server side. I think you will get another problem after this one. It has dependencies like this `require('fs');` which can't be used in front-end.

Comment: But i could use the ipc to make the back end handle that thought right?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy I don't know about IPC, but you definitely could use this lib on node.js and send http request.

Comment: so which file do i add this into in my project?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy code from my answer should be added to webpack config.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use either the `asar-unpack` or `asar-unpack-dir` parameters on the folders containing native modules.

Looks like it only takes one string, see the API docs for `asar-unpack-dir` for glob examples.
(The one string limitation appears to be an `asar` module limitation, if you think it should work as an array, you'd need to file an issue in their repository.)